# POST request with a simple string in body with Alamofire

Tags: ios, http, swift, request, alamofire

how is it possible to send a POST request with a simple string in the HTTP body with Alamofire in my iOS app?

As default Alamofire needs parameters for a request:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://mywebsite.example/post-request", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
```

These parameters contain key-value-pairs. But I don't want to send a request with a key-value string in the HTTP body.

I mean something like this:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://mywebsite.example/post-request", body: "myBodyString")
```

Answer (score 93):

Your example `Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://mywebsite.example/post-request", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])` already contains "foo=bar" string as its body.
But if you really want string with custom format. You can do this:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://mywebsite.example/post-request", parameters: [:], encoding: .Custom({
            (convertible, params) in
            var mutableRequest = convertible.URLRequest.copy() as NSMutableURLRequest
            mutableRequest.HTTPBody = "myBodyString".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
            return (mutableRequest, nil)
        }))
```

Note: `parameters` should not be `nil`

**UPDATE (Alamofire 4.0, Swift 3.0):**

In Alamofire 4.0 API has changed. So for custom encoding we need value/object which conforms to `ParameterEncoding` protocol.

```
extension String: ParameterEncoding {

    public func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {
        var request = try urlRequest.asURLRequest()
        request.httpBody = data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)
        return request
    }

}

Alamofire.request("http://mywebsite.example/post-request", method: .post, parameters: [:], encoding: "myBody", headers: [:])
```

Comment: This works perfectly, not only for simple but all kinds of JSON type mapped strings.

Comment: @silmaril in my situation I can get raw request from backend only if I use PUT method, could you please help me, why POST request can't see anything

Comment: .Custom isn't available anymore in Alamofire 4 Swift 3, and I am not able to find the alternative, any hints?

Comment: @Silmaril I posted question too, please answer that so I can close it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39573514/alamofire-4-swift-3-parameterencoding-custom

Comment: @Silmaril does not work for me. Converts "myBody" to `{ myBody: '' }`. Swift 3. Alamofire 4.0.0.

Comment: Can't tell you what are you doing wrong. I just double checked and it works.
```$ curl -i \
 -X POST \
 -H "Accept-Language: en;q=1.0" \
 -H "User-Agent: TestCalendar/1.0 (com.test.alamofire; build:1; iOS 10.0.0) Alamofire/4.0.0" \
 -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0, compress;q=0.5" \
 -d "myBody" \
 "http://mywebsite.com/post-request"```

Comment: the encoding parameter is not supposed to be a String

Comment: please double check my answer: there is an example of how string can become a valid encoding parameter with a help of extension

Comment: @Silmaril I have posted a question like this here if you can please share an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40385992/how-to-send-a-xml-object-with-alamofire

Comment: This is genius :) :) @quemeful the String is made to extend ParameterEncoding in the first pard of the code

Comment: Works perfectly. This should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: with Alamofire 4.7.3, Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10 everything looks perfect

Comment: Can you tell how to use it with more detail? what to do with encode function?

Comment: Last line `Alamofire.request(....` shows the usage. `encode` method is called by *Alamofire* during request putting `String` value in request's body with a help `encode` method

Comment: This isn't posting using the body, it's posting params

Answer (score 76):

You can do this:

1. I created a separated request Alamofire object.
2. Convert string to Data
3. Put in httpBody the data

   ```
   var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
   request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
   request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

   let pjson = attendences.toJSONString(prettyPrint: false)
   let data = (pjson?.data(using: .utf8))! as Data

   request.httpBody = data

   Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { (response) in


       print(response)

   }
   ```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's simple, does exactly what's needed, and without unnecessary extensions or conversions. Thanks, man.

Comment: P.S. I've "borrowed" your answer for another question - http://stackoverflow.com/a/42411188/362305

Comment: what is attendences, can you plz post a fuller snippet

Comment: @SyraKozZ Does not matter what attendances are, the only think that is important is pjson is a json string. You can put any json string there.

Answer (score 19):

If you use Alamofire, it is enough to set `encoding` type to `URLEncoding.httpBody`

With that, you can send your data as a string in the httpbody although you defined it as json in your code.

It worked for me..

*Updated for Badr Filali's question*:

```
var url = "http://..."
let _headers : HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]
let params : Parameters = ["grant_type":"password","username":"mail","password":"pass"]

let url =  NSURL(string:"url" as String)

request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: _headers).responseJSON(
    completionHandler: { response in response
        let jsonResponse = response.result.value as! NSDictionary
        
        if jsonResponse["access_token"] != nil
        {
            access_token = String(describing: jsonResponse["accesstoken"]!)
        }
    })
```

Comment: i ll update my answer and write the code a used, because i couldnt find how to write code as a comment from here.. Sorry for late.@Badr Filali

Comment: Worked for me, but my body need be a JSON, so, I changed the encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody to encoding: JSONEncoding.default and everything worked well.

Comment: Yes @AngeloPolotto thanks for contrubition:) This is about encoding type of service. Can be used depending your rest api as URLEncoding or JSONEncoding.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the problem I am facing is when I send a variable instead of `double quotes strings` and get error code `400`. How would I solve that?

Comment: Can you send me the example code may be i can help you better with this way @viper

Comment: This is what I did :-
   let parameters = [
            "password":"Admin@135",
            "grant_type":"password",
            "client_id":"Sipradi-mbl",
            "client_secret":"295265f0-c060-4782-9688-36854dba9af5",
            "scope":"offline_access",
            "username": edtEmail?.text
            ]

@CemalBAYRI

Comment: @viper i wanted you share me the fetching func that you called Alamofire. I cannot see any problem in this code line. if it is possible i can help you better

Comment: I am not getting problem while fetching data if I replace `edtEmail?.text` or any dynamic value with a static double quotes string.

Comment: Did you unwrap "edtMail.text?" ?? May be your textfields or etc. items are nil?

Answer (score 8):

I modified @Silmaril's answer to extend Alamofire's Manager. 
This solution uses EVReflection to serialize an object directly:

```
//Extend Alamofire so it can do POSTs with a JSON body from passed object
extension Alamofire.Manager {
    public class func request(
        method: Alamofire.Method,
        _ URLString: URLStringConvertible,
          bodyObject: EVObject)
        -> Request
    {
        return Manager.sharedInstance.request(
            method,
            URLString,
            parameters: [:],
            encoding: .Custom({ (convertible, params) in
                let mutableRequest = convertible.URLRequest.copy() as! NSMutableURLRequest
                mutableRequest.HTTPBody = bodyObject.toJsonString().dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
                return (mutableRequest, nil)
            })
        )
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Alamofire.Manager.request(.POST, endpointUrlString, bodyObject: myObjectToPost)
```

Answer (score 8):

Based on **[Illya Krit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42513496/4488252)**'s answer

### Details

- Xcode Version 10.2.1 (10E1001)
- Swift 5
- Alamofire 4.8.2

### Solution

```
import Alamofire

struct BodyStringEncoding: ParameterEncoding {

    private let body: String

    init(body: String) { self.body = body }

    func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {
        guard var urlRequest = urlRequest.urlRequest else { throw Errors.emptyURLRequest }
        guard let data = body.data(using: .utf8) else { throw Errors.encodingProblem }
        urlRequest.httpBody = data
        return urlRequest
    }
}

extension BodyStringEncoding {
    enum Errors: Error {
        case emptyURLRequest
        case encodingProblem
    }
}

extension BodyStringEncoding.Errors: LocalizedError {
    var errorDescription: String? {
        switch self {
            case .emptyURLRequest: return "Empty url request"
            case .encodingProblem: return "Encoding problem"
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: BodyStringEncoding(body: text), headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
     print(response)
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое !

Answer (score 5):

If you want to post string as raw body in request

```
return Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://mywebsite.com/post-request" , parameters: [:], encoding: .Custom({
            (convertible, params) in
            let mutableRequest = convertible.URLRequest.copy() as! NSMutableURLRequest

            let data = ("myBodyString" as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            mutableRequest.HTTPBody = data
            return (mutableRequest, nil)
        }))
```

Comment: Hi JITHINRAJ I posted a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40385992/how-to-send-a-xml-object-with-alamofire I want to send a xml body

Answer (score 5):

I have done it for array from strings. This solution is adjusted for string in body.

The "native" way from Alamofire 4:

```
struct JSONStringArrayEncoding: ParameterEncoding {
    private let myString: String

    init(string: String) {
        self.myString = string
    }

    func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {
        var urlRequest = urlRequest.urlRequest

        let data = myString.data(using: .utf8)!

        if urlRequest?.value(forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") == nil {
            urlRequest?.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        }

        urlRequest?.httpBody = data

        return urlRequest!
    }
}
```

And then make your request with:

```
Alamofire.request("your url string", method: .post, parameters: [:], encoding: JSONStringArrayEncoding.init(string: "My string for body"), headers: [:])
```

Answer (score 4):

I've used answer of @afrodev as reference. In my case I take parameter to my function as string that have to be posted in request. So, here is the code:

```
func defineOriginalLanguage(ofText: String) {
    let text =  ofText
    let stringURL = basicURL + "identify?version=2018-05-01"
    let url = URL(string: stringURL)

    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
    request.setValue("text/plain", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody = text.data(using: .utf8)

    Alamofire.request(request)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response)
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly you not get?

Answer (score 3):

```
let parameters = ["foo": "bar"]
              
    // All three of these calls are equivalent
    AF.request("https://httpbin.org/post", method: .post, parameters: parameters)
    AF.request("https://httpbin.org/post", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoder: URLEncodedFormParameterEncoder.default)
    AF.request("https://httpbin.org/post", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoder: URLEncodedFormParameterEncoder(destination: .httpBody))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
func paramsFromJSON(json: String) -> [String : AnyObject]?
{
    let objectData: NSData = (json.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))!
    var jsonDict: [ String : AnyObject]!
    do {
        jsonDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(objectData, options: .MutableContainers) as! [ String : AnyObject]
        return jsonDict
    } catch {
        print("JSON serialization failed:  \(error)")
        return nil
    }
}

let json = Mapper().toJSONString(loginJSON, prettyPrint: false)

Alamofire.request(.POST, url + "/login", parameters: paramsFromJSON(json!), encoding: .JSON)
```

Comment: What is Mapper?

Answer (score 2):

My case, posting alamofire with content-type: "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded", I had to change encoding of alampfire post request

from : JSONENCODING.DEFAULT
 to: URLEncoding.httpBody

here:

```
let url = ServicesURls.register_token()
    let body = [
        "UserName": "Minus28",
        "grant_type": "password",
        "Password": "1a29fcd1-2adb-4eaa-9abf-b86607f87085",
         "DeviceNumber": "e9c156d2ab5421e5",
          "AppNotificationKey": "test-test-test",
        "RegistrationEmail": email,
        "RegistrationPassword": password,
        "RegistrationType": 2
        ] as [String : Any]


    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: body, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody , headers: setUpHeaders()).log().responseJSON { (response) in
```

Answer (score -4):

**Xcode 8.X , Swift 3.X**

Easy Use;

```
 let params:NSMutableDictionary? = ["foo": "bar"];
            let ulr =  NSURL(string:"http://mywebsite.com/post-request" as String)
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: ulr! as URL)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params!, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)

            let json = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            if let json = json {
                print(json)
            }
            request.httpBody = json!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue);


            Alamofire.request(request as! URLRequestConvertible)
                .responseJSON { response in
                    // do whatever you want here
                   print(response.request)  
                   print(response.response) 
                   print(response.data) 
                   print(response.result)

            }
```