# How to send a POST request with BODY in swift

Tags: json, swift, put, alamofire

I'm trying to make a post request with a body in swift using Alamofire.

my json body looks like :

```
{
    "IdQuiz" : 102,
    "IdUser" : "iosclient",
    "User" : "iosclient",
    "List":[
        {
        "IdQuestion" : 5,
        "IdProposition": 2,
        "Time" : 32
        },
        {
        "IdQuestion" : 4,
        "IdProposition": 3,
        "Time" : 9
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to make `let` `list` with NSDictionnary which look like :

```
[[Time: 30, IdQuestion: 6510, idProposition: 10], [Time: 30, IdQuestion: 8284, idProposition: 10]]
```

and my request using Alamofire looks like :

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://myserver.com", parameters: ["IdQuiz":"102","IdUser":"iOSclient","User":"iOSClient","List":list ], encoding: .JSON)
            .response { request, response, data, error in
            let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                println(dataString)
        }
```

The request has an error and I believe the problem is with Dictionary list, cause if I make a request without the list it works fine, so any idea ?

---

I have tried the solution suggested but I'm facing the same problem :

```
 let json = ["List":list,"IdQuiz":"102","IdUser":"iOSclient","UserInformation":"iOSClient"]
        let data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(json, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted,error:nil)
        let jsons = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)



    Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://myserver.com", parameters: [:], encoding: .Custom({
        (convertible, params) in
        var mutableRequest = convertible.URLRequest.copy() as! NSMutableURLRequest
        mutableRequest.HTTPBody = jsons!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
        return (mutableRequest, nil)
    }))
        .response { request, response, data, error in
        let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
           println(dataString)
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [POST request with a simple string in body with Alamofire](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27855319/post-request-with-a-simple-string-in-body-with-alamofire)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but the post your provided doesn't help, and I'm not trying to pass a string as body, so can you please read the post carefully

Comment: @YasserB. Convert your JSON into a NSString (there is method for that), and then use the link of @Bhavin?

Comment: @Larme it would be really helpful if you provide an example

Comment: @Larme I have tried the solution suggested but I have the same problem the request doesn't work unless I delete the list from the son body

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You're close. The parameters dictionary formatting doesn't look correct. You should try the following:

```
let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [
    "IdQuiz" : 102,
    "IdUser" : "iosclient",
    "User" : "iosclient",
    "List": [
        [
            "IdQuestion" : 5,
            "IdProposition": 2,
            "Time" : 32
        ],
        [
            "IdQuestion" : 4,
            "IdProposition": 3,
            "Time" : 9
        ]
    ]
]

Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://myserver.com", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
    .responseJSON { request, response, JSON, error in
        print(response)
        print(JSON)
        print(error)
    }
```

Hopefully that fixed your issue. If it doesn't, please reply and I'll adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: How do I set some property of my JSON to null, since I cannot assign `nil` to `AnyObject`?

Comment: @JaseemAbbas check your version of Alamofire, if you're on v4.0+ check out my answer below

Comment: how to send this type of parameter in case encoding is .urlEncoding

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected dictionary value type 'AnyObject'

Comment: how to do if let's say the "List" parameter's value has like 1000 list elements?

Answer (score 197):

If you are using Alamofire v4.0+ then the accepted answer would look like this:

```
let parameters: [String: Any] = [
    "IdQuiz" : 102,
    "IdUser" : "iosclient",
    "User" : "iosclient",
    "List": [
        [
            "IdQuestion" : 5,
            "IdProposition": 2,
            "Time" : 32
        ],
        [
            "IdQuestion" : 4,
            "IdProposition": 3,
            "Time" : 9
        ]
    ]
]

Alamofire.request("http://myserver.com", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
    .responseJSON { response in
        print(response)
    }
```

Comment: Great! Change the accepted answer to this one please! :) or combine with the current one for both Alamofire 3 and 4 solutions.

Comment: Agreed - it's the explicit stating of `JSONEncoding` to disambiguate the type that did it for me.

Comment: @Gianni Carlo I used same as your answer but in my success response I'm receiving errors.

Comment: @Ramakrishna that might be related to the API you're consuming. To parse the response I usually use SwiftyJSON library, let me know what kind of errors you're receiving

Comment: @GianniCarlo Sir what about the Headers parameter, as in my request method it says one more parameter named "Headers"?

Comment: @Rishi you can add the headers as the last parameter `headers` (after parameter `encoding`) which receives a `HTTPHeaders` which is basically a dictionary <String:String>

Comment: for me, it's because of this `encoding: JSONEncoding.default`... hours of trying...

Comment: '*JSONEncoding.default*' worked for me. After chaning from `URLEncoding.default`

Comment: Make sure to use encoding and not encoder, that's from a different function.

Answer (score 50):

I don't like any of the other answers so far (except perhaps the [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41165560/362305) by SwiftDeveloper), because they either require you to deserialize your JSON, only for it to be serialized again, or care about the structure of the JSON itself.

The correct [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42162147/362305) has been posted by afrodev in another question. You should go and upvote it.

Below is just my adaption, with some minor changes (primarily explicit UTF-8 charset).

```
let urlString = "https://example.org/some/api"
let json = "{\"What\":\"Ever\"}"

let url = URL(string: urlString)!
let jsonData = json.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
request.setValue("application/json; charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpBody = jsonData

Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON {
    (response) in

    print(response)
}
```

Comment: I agree that @SwiftDeveloper's answer is better and (to my opinion) more complete than the 'correct' one you mention. But I would argue two points. One, that the 'correct answer' that you mention has the flaw that `toJSONString` is not a native method, so it's basically a black box which you have to implement. Two, the answer you give, provides a var `json` which starts out as a json string, realistically nobody has the parameters that way, unless you are converting and storing them locally that way.

Comment: @GianniCarlo 1) there's no `toJSONString` in my answer, 2) "realistically nobody has the parameters that way" - that's making a lot of assumptions; the JSON can be coming from quite different parts of the app, not related to making the request at all, and of which the networking code knows nothing.

Comment: Thanks for making my life easier!!!1 I 'm using Alamofire with Flask Backend. From Postman everything worked well.But from Alamofire it doesn't work.  HTTP body and URL parameters and how to set them. Thanks again.

Answer (score 20):

**Accepted answer in**
**Xcode 11** - **Swift 5** - **Alamofire 5.0**

```
func postRequest() {
    let parameters: [String: Any] = [
        "IdQuiz" : 102,
        "IdUser" : "iosclient",
        "User" : "iosclient",
        "List": [
            [
                "IdQuestion" : 5,
                "IdProposition": 2,
                "Time" : 32
            ],
            [
                "IdQuestion" : 4,
                "IdProposition": 3,
                "Time" : 9
            ]
        ]
    ]
    AF.request("http://myserver.com", method:.post, parameters: parameters,encoding: JSONEncoding.default) .responseJSON { (response) in
        print(response)
    }
}
```

Comment: IMPORTANT! Use encoding: JSONEncoding.default. I have been banging my head for hours ... the default is encoding for GET params.

Comment: Argument type 'JSONEncoding' does not conform to expected type 'ParameterEncoder'

Comment: @Takasur use JSONEncoding.default

Comment: I was giving up on life. then you saved me. Thank you

Comment: responseJSON is deprecated.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using `swift4` and `Alamofire v4.0` then the accepted code would look like this :

```
            let parameters: Parameters = [ "username" : email.text!, "password" : password.text! ]
            let urlString = "https://api.harridev.com/api/v1/login"
            let url = URL.init(string: urlString)
            Alamofire.request(url!, method: .put, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in
                 switch response.result
                {
                case .success(let json):
                    let jsonData = json as! Any
                    print(jsonData)
                case .failure(let error):
                    self.errorFailer(error: error)
                }
            }
```

Comment: Correct yes only add [encoding: JSONEncoding.default] in request 
working for me....

Answer (score 8):

**Xcode 8.X , Swift 3.X**

Easy Use;

```
    let params:NSMutableDictionary? = [
    "IdQuiz" : 102,
    "IdUser" : "iosclient",
    "User" : "iosclient",
    "List": [
        [
            "IdQuestion" : 5,
            "IdProposition": 2,
            "Time" : 32
        ],
        [
            "IdQuestion" : 4,
            "IdProposition": 3,
            "Time" : 9
        ]
    ]
];
            let ulr =  NSURL(string:"http://myserver.com" as String)
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: ulr! as URL)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params!, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)

            let json = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            if let json = json {
                print(json)
            }
            request.httpBody = json!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue);


            Alamofire.request(request as! URLRequestConvertible)
                .responseJSON { response in
                    // do whatever you want here
                   print(response.request)  
                   print(response.response) 
                   print(response.data) 
                   print(response.result)

            }
```

Answer (score 6):

**Alamofire 5.5 and Swift 5**

```
func postRequest() {
  let parameters: [String : Any] = [
    "IdQuiz" : 102,
    "IdUser" : "iosclient",
    "User" : "iosclient",
    "List": [
      [
        "IdQuestion" : 5,
        "IdProposition": 2,
        "Time" : 32
      ],
      [
        "IdQuestion" : 4,
        "IdProposition": 3,
        "Time": 9
      ]
    ]
  ]
  
  let url = URL(string: "http://myserver.com/api/post")!
  AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
    .validate()
    .responseJSON { response in
      switch response.result {
      case .success(let response):
        print(response)
      case .failure(let error):
        print(error.localizedDescription)
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I've slightly edited [SwiftDeveloper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41165560/6169303)'s answer, because it wasn't working for me. I added Alamofire validation as well.

```
let body: NSMutableDictionary? = [
    "name": "\(nameLabel.text!)",
    "phone": "\(phoneLabel.text!))"]

let url = NSURL(string: "http://server.com" as String)
var request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body!, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)

let json = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
if let json = json {
    print(json)
}
request.httpBody = json!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
let alamoRequest = Alamofire.request(request as URLRequestConvertible)
alamoRequest.validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
alamoRequest.responseString { response in

    switch response.result {
        case .success:
            ...
        case .failure(let error):
            ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Still works in Alamofire 4.9.1 and Swift 5.1.  Much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

There are few changes I would like to notify. You can access request, JSON, error from response object from now on.

```
        let urlstring = "Add URL String here"
        let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [
            "IdQuiz" : 102,
            "IdUser" : "iosclient",
            "User" : "iosclient",
            "List": [
                [
                    "IdQuestion" : 5,
                    "IdProposition": 2,
                    "Time" : 32
                ],
                [
                    "IdQuestion" : 4,
                    "IdProposition": 3,
                    "Time" : 9
                ]
            ]
        ]

        Alamofire.request(.POST, urlstring, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // URL response
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")
            }
            response.result.error
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

> Alamofire Fetch data with POST,Parameter and Headers

```
func feedbackApi(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let headers = [
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Authorization": "------"
        ]
        let url = URL(string: "---------")
        var parameters = [String:AnyObject]()
        parameters =  [
            "device_id":"-----" as AnyObject,
            "user_id":"----" as AnyObject,
            "cinema_id":"-----" as AnyObject,
            "session_id":"-----" as AnyObject,
        ]
       Alamofire.request(url!, method: .post, parameters: parameters,headers:headers).responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result{
                case.success(let data):
                    self.myResponse = JSON(data)
                    print(self.myResponse as Any)
                    let slide = self.myResponse!["sliders"]
                    print(slide)
                    print(slide.count)
                    for i in 0..<slide.count{
                        let single = Sliders(sliderJson: slide[i])
                        self.slidersArray.append(single)
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.getSliderCollection.reloadData()
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("dddd",error)
                }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I created Http POST request with swift that needs parameters with Json encoding and with headers.

Created API Client 
BKCAPIClient as a shared instance which will include all types of requests such as POST, GET, PUT, DELETE etc.

```
func postRequest(url:String, params:Parameters?, headers:HTTPHeaders?, completion:@escaping (_ responseData:Result<Any>?, _ error:Error?)->Void){
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON {
        response in
        guard response.result.isSuccess,
            (response.result.value != nil) else {
                debugPrint("Error while fetching data: \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
                completion(nil,response.result.error)
                return
        }
        completion(response.result,nil)
    }
}
```

Created Operation class that contains all data needed for particular request and also contains parsing logic inside completion block.

```
func requestAccountOperation(completion: @escaping ( (_ result:Any?, _ error:Error?) -> Void)){
    BKCApiClient.shared.postRequest(url: BKCConstants().bkcUrl, params: self.parametrs(), headers: self.headers()) { (result, error) in
        if(error != nil){
            //Parse and save to DB/Singletons.
        }
        completion(result, error)
    }
}
func parametrs()->Parameters{
    return ["userid”:”xnmtyrdx”,”bcode":"HDF"] as Parameters
}
func headers()->HTTPHeaders{
    return ["Authorization": "Basic bXl1c2VyOm15cGFzcw",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"] as HTTPHeaders
}
```

Call API In any View Controller where we need this data

```
func callToAPIOperation(){
let accOperation: AccountRequestOperation = AccountRequestOperation()
accOperation.requestAccountOperation{(result, error) in

}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone wondering how to proceed with models and stuff, see below

```
        var itemArr: [Dictionary<String, String>] = []
        for model in models {
              let object = ["param1": model.param1,
                            "param2": model.param2]
              itemArr.append(object as! [String : String])
        }

        let param = ["field1": someValue,
                     "field2": someValue,
                     "field3": itemArr] as [String : Any]

        let url: URLConvertible = "http://------"

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
            .responseJSON { response in
                self.isLoading = false
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    break
                case .failure:
                    break
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func get_Contact_list()
{
    ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.showSVProgressHUD(text: "Loading..")
    let cont_nunber = contact_array as NSArray
    print(cont_nunber)

    let token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "vAuthToken")!
    let apiToken = "Bearer \(token)"


    let headers = [
        "Vauthtoken": apiToken,
        "content-type": "application/json"
    ]

    let myArray: [Any] = cont_nunber as! [Any]
    let jsonData: Data? = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: myArray, options: .prettyPrinted)
    //        var jsonString: String = nil
    var jsonString = String()
    if let aData = jsonData {
        jsonString = String(data: aData, encoding: .utf8)!
    }

    let url1 = "URL"
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url1)!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    request.httpBody = jsonData as! Data

    //        let session = URLSession.shared

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.dismissSVProgressHUD()
            return
        }

        print("response = \(String(describing: response))")


        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")

        let json =  self.convertStringToDictionary(text: responseString!)! as NSDictionary
        print(json)

        let status = json.value(forKey: "status") as! Int

        if status == 200
        {

            let array = (json.value(forKey: "data") as! NSArray).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray


        }
        else if status == 401
        {
            ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.dismissSVProgressHUD()

        }
        else
        {
            ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.dismissSVProgressHUD()
        }


    }
    task.resume()
}

func convertStringToDictionary(text: String) -> [String:AnyObject]? {
    if let data = text.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String:AnyObject]
            return json
        } catch {
            print("Something went wrong")
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Alamofire ~5.2** and **Swift 5**

You can structure your parameter data

Work with [fake json](https://app.fakejson.com) api

```
struct Parameter: Encodable {
     let token: String = "xxxxxxxxxx"
     let data: Dictionary = [
        "id": "personNickname",
        "email": "internetEmail",
        "gender": "personGender",
     ]
}

 let parameters = Parameter()

 AF.request("https://app.fakejson.com/q", method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in
            print(response)
        }
```