# Swift : Separate classes for network requests

Tags: ios, swift, post, architecture, get

friends!, I am new to Swift. I need to make multiple API requests in one of my view controllers. If I put all the code in ViewController it will be messy.
So I am trying to develop this simple architecture to separate the concepts but I'm not sure whether it's the best approach to handle this situation.

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------*/
/* RestClient.swift */
/*-----------------------------------------------------*/
protocol RestClientDelegate {
    func dataDidLoad(json:String)
}
class RestClient {

    var delegate:RestClientDelegate

    //Handles all the network codes and exceptions
    func makeGetRequest(url){
        //send a get request to the server  
        //on error - handle erros 
        //on success - pass Json response to HttpUser class
        delegate.dataDidLoad(jsonOutput)
    }

}

/*-----------------------------------------------------*/
/* HttpUser.swift */
/*-----------------------------------------------------*/
protocol UserDelegate(){
    func usersDidLoad(usersArray:[User])//User object array
}
class HttpUser, RestClientDelegate {

    var delegate:UserDelegate

    func getUsers(){
        //Use rest client to make an api call
        var client = RestClient()
        client.delegate = self
        client.makeGetRequest("www.example.com/users")
    }

    //Once RestClient get the json string output, it will pass to
    //this function
    func dataDidLoad(json:String){
        //parse json - Handles json exceptions
        //populate user objects in an array
        //pass user array to the ViewController
        delegate.usersDidLoad(usersArray:[User])
    }

}

/*-----------------------------------------------------*/
/* UserViewController.swift */
/*-----------------------------------------------------*/
class UserViewController:UIViewController, UserDelegate {

    override viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Ask http user class to retrieve users
        var httpUser = HttpUser()
        httpUser.delegate = self
        httpUser.getUsers()
    }

    //Callback function to get users array
    func usersDidLoad(usersArray:[User]) {
        //now you have users object array
        //populate a table view
    }

}
```

1. RestClient.swift - Make the API request and pass a json output. This class contains all the code related to network **GET/POST** requests. I can modify this class in the future without affecting other classes.
2. HttpUser.swift - Get json output make an Users Array and pass it. This class does not care about network requests. It will just **handle the JSON response** and parse it into an object array. I will be having multiple of these. (ex: HttpBlogs, HttpComments)
3. UserViewController.swift - Get Users Array and populate a table view. This will handle only **sections related to the UI**.

Can you tell me is this approach is good to follow?
Is there a much better way to achieve this?

Thanks a lot everyone!

-Please note: I don't want to use 3rd party libraries like Alamofire in this case.

Comment: I'm quite new to iOS development but to my opinion your approach is very good. Actually I came up with the same approach when developing my first project and since then rather satisfied using it everywhere. A bit of advice - declare your delegate variables as weak variables.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this code in my App today. it seems pretty clean. :P

Comment: I usually follow this kind of architecture. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50868373/3656515

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is a good approach. You may want to think about displaying errors (ex: no internet connection) on the user interface for better user experience. In your example, you are handling your errors in `RestClient` class, but in case of any error, it is not upstreamed to `UserViewController` class to handle on the user interface.