# Trying to Post a dictionary to my backend

Tags: swift, alamofire, postman, swifty-json

I'm trying to Post a Dictionairy to my backend using Alamofire:

This is my code:

```
func postCheckUserPhonenumbers(phonenumbers:[String], completionHandler: (([AnyObject?], AnyObject?) -> Void)) {
    let urlString = Constant.apiUrl().stringByAppendingFormat(Constant.apiPostCheckUserPhonenumbers)
    
    let phoneNumbersDictionary = phonenumbers.map({ ["number": $0] })
    
    let json = JSON(phoneNumbersDictionary)
    print(json)
    
    Alamofire.request(.POST, urlString, parameters: phoneNumbersDictionary, encoding: .JSON).validate().responseJSON(completionHandler: {response in
        if response.result.isSuccess{
            if let json = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(json)
                
            }
        }
        if response.result.isFailure{
            
        }
    })
}
```

It won't compile because the phoneNumbersDictionairy is not conforming to the expected argument:

[image]

The print(json) however is printing exactly what I have in my Postman though. This is the body I want to post.
The printed statement:

```
[
  {
    "number" : "85555512"
  },
  {
    "number" : "85551212"
  },
  {
    "number" : "55648583"
  }
]
```

My Postman:

[image]

How can I make this happen?

Comment: how array of `phonenumbers` looks like?

Comment: Your error means that this Alamofire method sends a dictionary to the web, but you are trying to send an array of dictionaries which it obviously can't send.

Comment: Basically, your 'phoneNumbersDictionary' is not a Dictionary. It is an array.

Comment: This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026916/sending-json-array-via-alamofire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this:

```
func postCheckUserPhonenumbers(phonenumbers:[String], completionHandler: (([AnyObject?], AnyObject?) -> Void)) {
    let urlString = Constant.apiUrl().stringByAppendingFormat(Constant.apiPostCheckUserPhonenumbers)

    let phoneNumbersDictionary = phonenumbers.map({ ["number": $0] })

    let inputJSON = try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(phoneNumbersDictionary, options: [])

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = inputJSON

    Alamofire.request(request).validate().responseJSON(completionHandler: {response in
        if response.result.isSuccess{
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(value)
                let jsonString = json.rawString()
                if let users:Array<User> = Mapper<User>().mapArray(jsonString) {
                    completionHandler(users, nil)
                } else {
                    completionHandler([nil], nil)
                }
            }
        }
        if response.result.isFailure{
            let message = ApiMessage()
            message.message = "No users found"
            completionHandler([nil],message)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, `phonenumbers.map({["number": $0]})`returns an array of type `[[String:String]]`, as you can see on the image I attached.
[image: Playground]

Alamorfire expects an array of the type `[String: AnyObejct]?` as parameter.

But perhaps [How to send a post request with body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31982513/how-to-send-a-post-request-with-body-in-swift?answertab=votes#tab-top!) or [Sending json array via alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026916/sending-json-array-via-alamofire?answertab=votes#tab-top!) can help you.