# Post method request Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

I'm using Swift 3 and Alamofire 4.0.

I want to create similar Alamofire POST request as Postman request shown in screenshot:

[image]

I've tried with these lines of code:

```
var parameters:  [String: Any] = [
    "client_id" : "xxxxxx",
    "client_secret" : "xxxxx",
    "device_token" : "xxxx",
    "fullname" : "xxxxx",
    "gender": "xxx"
]

Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in
print(response)
}
```

But I got this error:

[image]

How to implement POST request with Body as form-data using Alamofire in Swift 3?

Comment: You have troubles with serialisation of response. Is it in JSON format?

Comment: Looking at the error it refers that the *response* is not a valid JSON, try to look at the response first. (eg. use Charles)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31982513/how-to-send-a-post-request-with-body-in-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Swift 3.0 - Alamofire - Working code for multipart form data upload *

// Parameters

```
let params: [String : String] =
   ["UserId"    : "\(userID)",
    "FirstName" : firstNameTF.text!,
    "LastName"  : lastNameTF.text!,
    "Email"     : emailTF.text!
   ]
```

// And upload

```
Alamofire.upload(
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

            for (key, value) in params
            {
                    multipartFormData.append((value.data(using: .utf8))!, withName: key)
            }
    },
        to: url,
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    debugPrint(response)

                }
                upload.uploadProgress(queue: DispatchQueue(label: "uploadQueue"), closure: { (progress) in


                })

            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
    }
    )
```

Let me know if you still have issues with it.

Comment: I'm new to Swift programming. What does `completionhandler()` mean? I got an error: `Use of unresolved identifier 'completionhandler'`, but the source code works well after I delete it and I got the JSON response from the server.

Comment: What is it for? Is it just your code in your project? :D

Comment: @user1808 - I have edited the answer and removed the completion handler 
Yes It is a example in swift 3 using latest Alamofire to post a multipartFormData to server.

Answer (score 0):

after too much try I have succeded so try this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let parameters: Parameters = ["client_id": "1","user_token":"xxxxxxxx"]
                // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let url = "http://xxxxxxxxxxx/index.php/Web_api/get_client_profile"
        //let timeParameter =  self.getLastTimeStamp()
        self.request = Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters:parameters)
        if let request = request as? DataRequest {
            request.responseString { response in
                //PKHUD.sharedHUD.hide()
                do{
                    let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSDictionary
                    print(dictionary)

                }catch{

                }
            }
        }
    }

    var request: Alamofire.Request? {
        didSet {
            //oldValue?.cancel()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can post a request using Alamofire.

```
let url = ""
let headers    = [ "Content-Type" : "application/json"]
let para : Parameters = [ "data" : JSONObject]
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: para, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers : headers)
    .responseJSON { response in

        print(response)
        print(response.result)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to worry about.
Alamofire request method not changed so much(For Swift 3.0) if in case you know how to do that in Swift 2.0/2.2. If you understand the old method then you can easily understand this one also. Now lets take a closer look on the following boilerplate -

```
Alamofire.request(apiToHit, method: .post, parameters: parametersObject, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headerForApi).responseJSON { response in switch response.result{

    case .success(_):
        if let receivedData: Any = response.result.value{
            if let statusCode: Int = response.response?.statusCode {
               //Got the status code and data. Do your data pursing task from here.
            }
        }else{
             //Response data is not valid, So do some other calculations here
        }
    case .failure(_):
            //Api request process failed. Check for errors here.
    }
```

Now here in my case -

1. **apiToHit**    //Your api url string
2. **.post**    //Method of the request. You can change this method as per you need like .post, .get, .put, .delete etc.
3. **parametersObject**   // Parameters needed for this particular api. Same in case you are sending the "body" on postman etc. Remember this parameters should be in form of `[String: Any]`. If you don't need this then you can just pass `nil`.
4. **JSONEncoding.default** //This the encoding process. In my case I am setting this as `.default` which is expected here. You can change this to `.prettyPrinted` also if you need.
5. **headerForApi** //This is the header which you want to send while you are requesting the api. In my case it is in `[String: String]` format. If you don't need this then you can just pass `nil`.
6. **.responseJSON** //Expecting the response as in JSON format. You can also change this as you need.

Now, in my request I am using Switch inside the request closure to check the result like `response in switch response.result{`.

Inside `case .success(_):` case I am also checking for result data and `http` status code as well like this

```
if let receivedData: Any = response.result.value{
    if let statusCode: Int = response.response?.statusCode {
 }
}
```

Hope this helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
class func alamofireMethod(methods: Alamofire.HTTPMethod , url : URLConvertible , parameters : [String : Any],need_flag_inside : Bool = false, paramJson : Bool = true ,need_loader : Bool = true,Header: [String: String],handler:@escaping CompletionHandler,errorhandler : @escaping ErrorHandler)
{
    if NetworkController.sharedInstance.checkNetworkStatus()
    {
        var alamofireManager : Alamofire.SessionManager?
        var hed = Header

        if let tok = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "TOKEN") as? String {
            hed = ["Authorization":"Bearer \(tok)"]
        }

        if need_loader {
           // DELEGATE.showLoader()
        }
        var UrlFinal = ""
        do
        {
           try UrlFinal = baseURL + url.asURL().absoluteString
        }
        catch{}


        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 25
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 25
        configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders  = hed

        alamofireManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)

        alamofireManager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
    let json = JSON(parameters)
    guard let jsonDict = json.dictionaryObject else {
        return
    }
    var jsonData = Data()
    do {

        jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonDict, options: [])

    } catch {
        //handle error
        print(error)
    }

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: UrlFinal)!)
    request.httpMethod = methods.rawValue

    if methods == .post || methods == .put
    {
        //check  here
        if paramJson {
            hed["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
            request.httpBody = jsonData
        }else{
            let postString = self.getPostString(params: parameters)
            request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        }

    }
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = hed

        Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON(queue: nil, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) { (response) in
        print(parameters)
        print(UrlFinal)
        print(hed)
      //  DELEGATE.hideLoader()

        if response.result.isSuccess
        {
            print(response)
            handler(response.result.value! as AnyObject)
        }
        else if response.response?.statusCode == 401
        {                
        //    DELEGATE.redirectToLogin()
         //   DELEGATE.showToast(message: "Token Expired")
        }
        else{
        //    DELEGATE.showToast(message: default_failure)
            errorhandler(response.result.error! as NSError)
            print(response.result.error as Any)
        }
    }
    }else{
      //  DELEGATE.showToast(message: "Please check your internet connection.")
    }
}
```

### Alomofire With Post and Put Method In swift