# i got response error .. any idea ? using swift with Alamo fire i have to send post request as http body row

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
let parameters = ["order": ["line_items": [
    ["variant_id": 18055889387589, "quantity": 11]]]] as [String : Any]


Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.prettyPrinted, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success:
        print("response is ",response)
    case .failure(let error):
        print(0,"Error")
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this question and answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31982513/how-to-send-a-post-request-with-body-in-swift

Answer (score -2):

```
let parameters = ["order": ["line_items": [
    ["variant_id": 18055889387589, "quantity": 11]]]] as [String : Any]

let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters)
let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
```

i think the problem is your parametres try this one

Comment: how to assign jsonString to http body ?