# Alamofire 4 Swift 3 ParameterEncoding Custom

Tags: ios, alamofire, swift3

I updated my project to Swift 3 and Alamofire 4. I was using custom Encoding, but it's changed to other encoding methods. I am not able to find the alternative/equivalent to this:

```
alamoFire.request(urlString, method: HTTPMethod.post, parameters: [:], encoding: .Custom({
        (convertible, params) in

        let mutableRequest = convertible.URLRequest.copy() as! NSMutableURLRequest
        let data = (body as NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        mutableRequest.httpBody = data
        return (mutableRequest, nil)

    }), headers: headers()).responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in

        switch responseObject.result {
        case .success(let JSON):
            success(responseObject: JSON)

        case .failure(let error):
            failure(error: responseObject)
        }
    }
```

I also tried by making URLRequest object and simple request its also giving me errors

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString)!)
    let data = (body as NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    request.httpBody = data
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers()

    alamoFire.request(request).responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in

        switch responseObject.result {
        case .success(let JSON):
            success(JSON)

        case .failure(let error):
            failure(responseObject, error)
        }
    }
```

Do point me in some direction, how to attach httpbody with the Alamofire 4

Comment: What is in your body? You sure that it converts as a String? And how do you wanna send it? as a JSON? or just as a String?

Comment: @AlvinVarghese Raw data

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Alamofire 4.0 you should use `ParameterEncoding` protocol. Here is an example, which makes any `String` `UTF8` encodable.

```
extension String: ParameterEncoding {

    public func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {
        var request = try urlRequest.asURLRequest()
        request.httpBody = data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)
        return request
    }

}

Alamofire.request("http://mywebsite.com/post-request", method: .post, parameters: [:], encoding: "myBody", headers: [:])
```

Comment: how does enconding: "myBody" relate to any other code in this example? this answer is uncomplete althought accepted.

Comment: "myBody" is just an example string, which represents body of your request. By default you can't use `String` as `coding` parameter, but with a help of `extension` in my example you can.

Comment: Interesting. There should be a more elegant way of providing a raw enconding than extending String's class, thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 12):

Try  this method?

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: HTTPMethod.post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: nil).responseObject(completionHandler: { (response : DataResponse<T>)  in

})
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as does not require custom implementation of `ParameterEncoding`