# How to make a POST request use Alamofire 4.0 And the parameter is text not json

Tags: json, swift, http, post, alamofire

I want to make a POST request use Alamofire 4.0,And,I hope that my request parameter is transmitted to the server in the form of text rather than json. Please help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you should use .Custom for encoding  parameter and create your own custom encoding and add it to your HTTP body in earlier alamofire , but in Alamafire 4.0 you should extend the ParameterEncoding

```
extension String: ParameterEncoding {

public func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {
    var request = try urlRequest.asURLRequest()
    request.httpBody = data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)
        return request
    }
}
```

you can find example code here  -> [stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28552198/2739657)

Comment: I said parameter is HTTPBody not response

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
 func API_getSubject(id:String) {


    MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
    let param = ["idnumber" : id];

    print("param == \(param)")

    Alamofire.request(Config.BASE_URL + "subject_list", method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
        .responseJSON {
            response in debugPrint(response)     // prints detailed description of all response properties

            //to get JSON return value
            if let result = response.result.value {
                let JSON = result as! NSDictionary

                if JSON.value(forKey: "status") as! NSNumber == 1 {
                    self.ary_responce = (JSON["subjects"]! as! NSArray).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
                    self.aTable.reloadData()
                }
                else{
                    self.Alert(msg: "\(JSON["message"]!)")
                }
            }
            else{
                if let error = response.result.error {
                    self.Alert(msg: error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDs(for: self.view, animated: true)
                MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
            }
    }
}
```