# not receiving json Data in Alamofire request with http body

Tags: json, swift2, alamofire

Im using the following code to send a POST request to the web server with an http parameter, in order to receive the JSON Data

```
Alamofire.request(.POST,myURL, parameters: [:], encoding: .Custom({
        (convertible, params) in
        var mutableRequest = convertible.URLRequest.copy() as NSMutableURLRequest
        mutableRequest.HTTPBody = "MyBody".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
        return (mutableRequest, nil)
    }))
```

ive got it from stackoverflow  : [POST request with a simple string in body with Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27855319/post-request-with-a-simple-string-in-body-with-alamofire)
but im not receiving any data.
im using swift 2.3 and alamofire 3.5.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

simple **POST** call with **Alamofire4** & **Swift3** :

```
    let url: String = "https://example.com"
    let parameter = ["X": "10", "Y": "20"]


    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameter, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil)
        .responseJSON { (response) in

            let result = response.result.value
            print(result)

    }
```

simple **GET** call to see some **JSON** result :

```
        let url: String = "https://example.com"
        Alamofire.request(url)
        .responseJSON { response in

            let result = response.result.value
            print(result)
    }
```