# How to make rest api post calls in swift 3.0

Tags: python, swift

so I have been using requests in python to make an api call and currently use it in this way:

```
import requests

data = {"tag":"hello","value":"ayush"}
r = requests.post('MY URl', data)
```

and now I want to implement the same kind of post api call in swift,(in the shortest and easiest way possible)so can you please help

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use Alamofire:
[POST request with a simple string in body with Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27855319/post-request-with-a-simple-string-in-body-with-alamofire) - but this will require an additional library in your project

You could also do it "by hand" with internal frameworks provided by Apple, via `URLRequest` / `URLSession`: [HTTP Request in Swift with POST method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26364914/http-request-in-swift-with-post-method)

Comment: yeah ok thanks (i have already tried it didn't work for me) thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You asked fast and easy, this just fires and forgets. If you want to handle the response see [HTTP Request in Swift with POST method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26365148/4465531) suggested above by [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1646335/andreas-oetjen). For an elegant approach check out Swift Talk [Networking: POST Requests](https://talk.objc.io/episodes/S01E08-networking-post-requests) (these discussions are excellent).

If you're using HTTP vs. HTTPS you have to set the project's Info.plist NSAppTransportSecurity property Allow Arbitrary Loads to true.

```
    let url = URL(string: "http://yourdomain.com")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = "{\"tag\":\"hello\",\"value\":\"ayush\"}".data(using: .utf8)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request).resume()
```