# Post Json string in Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

How to post a json string using Alamofire. Alamofire request takes only Dictionary type as parameter: `[String : Any]`. But I want to pass a json string as a parameter, not Dictionary.

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, 
         parameters: [String : Any], // <-- takes dictionary !!
         encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [:])
```

Comment: did u resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to convert your json data to native dictionary and use it as intended:

```
func jsonToDictionary(from text: String) -> [String: Any]? {
    guard let data = text.data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
    let anyResult = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    return anyResult as? [String: Any]
}
```

Usage:

```
var params = jsonToDictionary(from: json) ?? [String : Any]()
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [:])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `encoding: JSONEncoding.default` and your parameter data in the form of `[String : Any]` while you passing the data Alamofire encode your `[String : Any]` to `json` becuse you already mentioned  your encoding method will be `JSONEncoding.default` server will receive encoded `JSON`

Comment: this is not what OP sought after; he wants to pass a string instead of a dict. E.g.: "This is a string", *BUT* ["this is" : "dictionary"]

Answer (score 0):

duplicate:[POST request with a simple string in body with Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28552198/6202715)

```
extension String: ParameterEncoding {

    public func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {
        var request = try urlRequest.asURLRequest()
        request.httpBody = data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)
        return request
    }

}

Alamofire.request("http://mywebsite.com/post-request", method: .post, parameters: [:], encoding: "myBody", headers: [:])
```