# How to make login Web service using alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, web-services, alamofire

I am new in using web service in swift.I have web service url

```
http://dev.nsol.sg/projects/sneakers/Api/login
Method: POST
```

**Required Parameters:**

- username
- password
- device_id    (hidden)
- device_token (hidden)
- os_type      (hidden)
- os_version   (hidden)

**Response:**

> success = 0 (error), 1 (success)
>
> message = Description of result if success = 0 then message will have the detail description
>
> data = if success = 1 then we will have complete user profile in data object
>
> profileurl = User Profile User + Use profile_pic to display Picture

How i can make the login web service using *Alamofire*?

Comment: [refer this so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27855319/post-request-with-a-simple-string-in-body-with-alamofire)

Comment: There are thousands of tutorial available for alamofire. In Stackvoerflow no one going to write code for you !! , You have to show your tired code