# Swift & Firebase Functions: HTTPS authenticate the user

Tags: node.js, swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions

i have some https Cloud Functions which I want to secure by authorizing the user sending the request.

My function looks like this:

```
exports.authTester = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
const tokenID = req.get('Authorization').split('Bearer ')[1];

return admin.auth().verifyIDToken(tokenID)
    .then((decoded) => res.status(200).send(decoded))
    .catch((err) => res.status(401).send(err));
    console.log(decoded);
});
```

Within my App I'm calling the function via Alamofire:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get).responseString { (response) in
    if let dta = response.response?.statusCode{
        print(response)
    }
}
```

However, my console logs that the function crashes due to the hint:

"Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at exports.authTester.functions.https.onRequest (...)"

How can I solve this issue?

Thank´s!

Comment: Your function is expecting an Authorization HTTP header. How are you passing it from the client?  Have you tried logging it in the function before you work with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this error because you aren't invoking your cloud function with the proper command that is to passing the token in the HTTP header.

You'd be doing something like:

```
let token: String = "Bearer" + ...
let header = ["Authorization": token]
// then you pass your header into Alamofire request
```

Here is a link to [on how to do a POST Request from Alamofire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27855319/post-request-with-a-simple-string-in-body-with-alamofire), 
a link from [Alamofire Docs](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#making-a-request)

Comment: I don't think there is going to be any difference between GET and POST here.  They both send headers.

Comment: but what if the token needed to be passed within the request body ? then POST would be necessary wouldn't you agree ?

Comment: The function code is expecting the token in a header.  It's not even touching anything else from the request, which is making POST irrelevant here.

Comment: yeah you are right, the OP just needs to pass the headers fields of the Alamofire Request.

Comment: and the comment I did ealier was because most of the time certain apis are waiting on the `Autorization` token from the body instead of the header

Comment: Thank´s for the answer! Only point is that "Bearer" needs to be "Bearer " with a blankspace.